# Is there a per-app language action to open the settings screen from the app?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

To open the notification settings from an intent, we can use the action `Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS`

There are a lot of different actions available to open specific settings screens but I didn't find one to open the new [per-app language settings screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-language).

Am I missing it?

I tried differents strings like `"android.settings.APP_LANGUAGES_SETTINGS"` but none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ACTION_APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS` intent.
It takes in a `Uri` to specify the app.

Here's how to use is:

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS)
val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", context?.packageName, null)
intent.data = uri
    
startActivity(intent)
```

You can find documentation on it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS).

---

### Edit

As @ProgrAmmar pointed out, this was added in API level 33.

You can check for that like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    // Your code for API level 33 or higher
    // Enable your feature here
} else {
    // Your code for API levels below 33
    // Handle the case where the feature is not supported
}
```

The version code for API level 33 is `TIRAMISU` but you can check the whole list of code names [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES).

**Note:**
It is important that you consider building an alternative for your users when coding like this. For selecting an per-app language that might not be so important (as the users won't be missing it because no other app supports it either) but if there is functionality that is integral to your app, you should add an option for the other users or reconsider your approach.

Comment: This Intent doesn't work with all the OEMs. I am testing on my Android tablet having MIUI and it crashes.

Comment: @MehulKanzariya It was added in API level 33, so you will have to surround it in a sdk level check. Emil I think you should add the level check in your code.

Comment: @ProgrAmmar yes you are right. I am using it in an app that is only available for API level 33 and up, but I will update my answer accordingly, thanks